# Tinymce in Winforms ( Windows Application) using C# - SetContent not working

Tags: c#, winforms, tinymce

I am using TinyMce in my Winforms ( Windows application ) using C#. Everything else works fine. i.e. I am able to Get Content of TinyMce and storing in Database. But when I pull content from Database and try to show in TinyMce, the contents are not loaded. In fact SetContent function is not called at all. I even tried calling SetContent without parameters but it was not called. On the same hand GetContent is called successfully.
Here are both of these functions ( JavaScript functions present in tinymce.htm file)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetContent() {
    alert('GetContent is called');
    console.log('GetContent is called');
    return tinyMCE.get('editorcontent').getContent();
}

function SetContent(htmlContent) { //This is not called. Even if I remove the htmlContent parameter
    alert('SetContent is called');
    console.log('SetContent is called');
    tinyMCE.get('editorcontent').setContent(htmlContent);
}
</script>
```

And here is my C# code where I am calling these functions ( its a property ).

```
public string HtmlContent
{
    get
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        if (webBrowserControl != null && webBrowserControl.Document != null)
        {
            object html = webBrowserControl.Document.InvokeScript("GetContent");
            content = html as string;
        }
        return content;
    }
    set
    {
        if (webBrowserControl != null && webBrowserControl.Document != null)
        {
            //Code reaches here. I confirmed through breakpoint. I even tried 
            //removing the parameter but it didn't worked. SetContent was never 
            //called. 
            webBrowserControl.Document.InvokeScript("SetContent", new object[] { value });
        }
    }
}
```

What can be the issue? How can I set contents of tinyMCE dynamically in a winforms ( Windows application ) using C#?

Comment: Are you sure Internet Explorer is (fully) supported? Is it running in quirks here? Have you at least set the compat mode to IE11? Have you tried with a WebView2 component instead (highly recommended)?

Comment: @Jimi Even though my issue has been solved. The reason was that SetContent was not being called in same event where tinMCE was initialized. I am using Timer event to set the contents. But I am eager to know that if WebView2 can be used as WYSIWYG editor? I mean can we format Text/Html and insert images just like we do with TinMCE ? Isn't WebView2 is for displaying web contents only ?

Comment: My TinyMCE implementation is a .NET WPF using Chromium. What I found is carriage returns and/or newlines in the html will cause setContent to completely fail. Also because of the way I have to invoke JavaScript using a string, also must make sure there are no single quote characters (or escape them might work, haven't tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been resolved. Posting answer for any future people coming to this link with same issue.
SetContent was not called in same event (Form_Load) where TinyMCE was initialized (Created). So, I used a Timer Tick event (1 second) delay to loadthe Html using SetContent.
Please not that Thread.Sleep (in Form_Load) was not functional either.